# Protect images from non-authenticated users

Tags: php, .htaccess, authentication, session

I'd like to protect the images (for example, private photo gallery) with a users log-in.
I don't use htaccess (because of usability: you cannot log out, design is shitty, ...) but instead a php/db login + session for authentication. This works well for my own PHP scripts.

However, the photos are note protected if you enter the specific URL (as they would be with htaccess authentication).

**The question is: [how] can the photos/images be protected in the same way?**
It would be perfect to have a rule like "for all images, call 'session.php' first".

*Note*: I cannot deliver all images via a PHP script (like getimage.php?img=photo123.jpg) because I also use external scripts for the photo gallery, blog etc.

*Note 2*: One option would be a referral check in htaccess, however there are cases where no referer is sent and the photo should still be shown (because the user authenticated correctly).

Comment: What exactly is up with your first *Note*? What external scripts are you talking about and how do they impact your ability to use PHP scripts to serve the files? Are the images hosted *externally* and that server isn't requiring authentication? Then there isn't a lot you can do to protect them. You could still serve them through a PHP script on your server as a reverse-proxy, but they'll still be publicly available directly on that other server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. What I meant was that I cannot *change* some PHP files and how images are included. For example I cannot change "img/photo.jpg" to "get.php?f=img/photo.jpg" in all scripts.

Comment: You don't have to, you just need to configure your server to route requests for `img/photo.jpg` through a PHP file. This can be done with .htaccess rules: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20563773/476